# JavaScript function is not working

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have this line in a button click method on my aspx.cs file

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), 
                                   "RefreshOpener", 
                                   "RefreshParent()", 
                                    true);
```

I have this code on aspx file

```
function RefreshParent() {              
                   window.opener.location.href = window.opener.location.href;

        }
```

When I debug th code, it comes to this line `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), 
                                       "RefreshOpener", 
                                       "RefreshParent()", 
                                        true);`
 but does not go to aspx file to run the JS code.

The most frustrating part is I have used the same things on some other pages with the same methods and they worked but this time it is not.

This is the button mentioned

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="Button_KAYDET" 
                 runat="server" 
                 CausesValidation="False"
                 ImageUrl="~/images/butonlar/kucuk/kaydet.jpg"
                 OnClick="Button_KAYDET_Click"
                 meta:resourcekey="Button_KAYDETResource1" />
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe this is too obvious, but don't you need a semicolon after the function call? "RefreshParent();" instead of just "RefreshParent()".

Comment: Well, @Smelch I tried that too, I am trying to figure out the problem for hours.As I alos mentioned in the question I used same methods, same sentences, same calls, on other pages and they are working perfectly but thanks for the idea.

Comment: Does `RefreshParent()` get hit at all?

Comment: No Mr.Town that is the problem @Town

Comment: So this is in a popup and you are trying to refresh the parent page?

Comment: Yes, Mr.R and yes I tried many things :).It seems like ScriptManager is what I needed in this situation.@Bala R

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the button is placed inside of an UpdatePanel then you'll need to use  the ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript method ([MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerstartupscript.aspx)).

Your code should look like:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "RefreshOpener","RefreshParent()", true);
```

Comment: I have this `<form id="form1" runat="server">`

Comment: `RefreshParent()` should be a string.

Comment: Thanks Alison. I did that a couple minutes ago when 1nstein suggested, and it s working thank you so much for your interest.However, in the other pages I mentioned and those having the same methods and working the same button is placed inside an UpdatePanel, too.And I had no problem with them.I do not understand why I had problem with this one.

Answer (score 0):

Does the `Button_KAYDET` button placed in an `UpdatePanel`?
if it is use the `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript method instead of the ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript`

Comment: I checked that too, yes it is.

Comment: then use the ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript method instead of the ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript

Comment: Please post questions in the comments of the question. Leave answers to the solutions to the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Onestein we should hang out :D that is my answer "then use the ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript method instead of the ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript "

Comment: But I still don't understand the difference, that Button_KAYDET is in an UpdatePanel on the pages these same methods are working, too. And they are ok, but this one is not.

Comment: This looks strange as an accepted answer! @1stein, can you edit your answer to actually include the answer? :)