# How can I scroll down to a multiline TextBox's bottom line, Javascript's scrollIntoView is not working for this

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, chatroom

I am trying to create a basic video and text chat web site.In the room page I have the video as flash and a textbox(multiline) which shows all the messages sent to the room and one textbox for users to type and send by clicking the button beside it

```
<tr>
    <td>
         <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdtPnlMesajlar" runat="server" EnableViewState="true">
               <ContentTemplate>
                      <table>
                             <tr>
                                 <td>
                                     <asp:TextBox ID="TxtBxOdaMesajlari" 
                                      runat="server" ReadOnly="true"
                                      TextMode="MultiLine"
                                      Width="475" Height="100"  >
                                     </asp:TextBox>
                                 </td>
                             </tr>
                             <tr>
                                 <td>
                                     <asp:TextBox ID="TxtBxMesaj" runat="server" 
                                      Width="412"></asp:TextBox>
                                     <asp:Button ID="BttnGonder" runat="server"
                                      Text="Gönder" Width="55"
                                      OnClick="BttnGonder_click"/>
                                 </td>
                             </tr>
                      </table>
               </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
       </td>
   </tr>
```

Above is my code, all those controls are in an `UpdatePanel` so when user clicks `BttnGonder` that no flickers happens.

When user presses the button what he typed is concataned to `TxtBxOdaMesajlari` in the below method called `BttnGonder_click`.

```
protected void BttnGonder_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string uyeId = Session["UyeId"].ToString();
            string mesaj = uyeId + " : " + TxtBxMesaj.Text;
            TxtBxOdaMesajlari.Text = TxtBxOdaMesajlari.Text + Environment.NewLine + mesaj;
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "txtbxmesajlarslide", "buttonClicked();", true);

        }
```

Well after a number of messages scrollbars appear `TxtBxOdaMesajlari` can be seen , however the new messages cannot be seen because `TxtBxOdaMesajlari` does not slide/scroll down automatically.I searched about this and found this example [Multi User Chat Room Using ASP.NET 2.0 and AJAX](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ASPNetChat.aspx) it uses Javascript's `scrollIntoView()` so I decided to use it but the page gets flickered and scrolling does not work at all.Maybe I am using the wrong control or the wrong way to do is.
I am using ASP.NET 4.0 if that matters a lot.

On aspx file

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function buttonClicked() {
                $get("TxtBxOdaMesajlari").scrollIntoView("true");
            }
</script>
```

I am using `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` because the controls are in an `UpdatePanel` as it was suggested and worked fine at [Accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6201649/647884) by user:3742 of [JavaScript function is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201559/javascript-function-is-not-working).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scrollIntoView is used to scroll the textbox itself into view, not its contents.

In order to scroll to the end of the textbox, you can use:

```
function buttonClicked() {
    var textBox = $get("TxtBxOdaMesajlari");
    textBox.scrollTop = textBox.scrollHeight;
}
```